# Does installing rEFIt void my warranty?

Tags: warranty, efi

I would like to install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/). Will it void my warranty, even though it can be uninstalled?

Comment: What part of your warranty are you worried about? Have you looked at it to know what it says?

Comment: Couple things...What is rEFIT? And why would it void your warranty? Are you on an iOS device? Or on a computer with OS X? My suggestion is that you expand your question to fix this.

Comment: I added the link to refit, but somehow it was lost... now it's fixed. But the best solution to me is to edit the refit tag, but I don't have tag editing privileges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) is software and therefore should not affect the hardware warranty.

However, if you're concerned about that and want to avoid trouble (there's always the odd [thickheaded customer service rep](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1020955), even at Apple), you can simply wipe your drive and do a clean OS X reinstall before you send your machine in for service (and restore from backup once you get it back). rEFIt does not modify your EFI or anything else, so there'll be no trace left of it if you do so.

Comment: These magic words set you free at Apple's service counter anytime someone says software voided anything. "I have a backup and if you feel restoring the software to factory defaults will help you determine if I have a hardware problem, by all means - make it so."

Answer (score 0):

I have a user with a rMBP that was told by the GeniusBar that his warranty was voided by using rEFIt to install Linux. Trouble is, the system never had Linux on it, only a BootCamp partition which has since been removed.

They said removing the "unauthorized software" would reinstate the warranty. 
Run the following two lines and reboot to remove rEFIt.

```
sudo rm -r /efi
sudo rm -r /Library/StartupItems/rEFItBlesser
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The warranty covers hardware support and unless you have AppleCare, Apple doesn't technically owe you any software support. Now, if I showed up for hardware service and didn't let Apple restore my device to factory boot conditions, I'd expect to get no further help as well. Also - the whole concept of "voided warranty" rings as someone who doesn't understand contracts and legal agreements. You don't invalidate an agreement when the item being discussed isn't even contemplated to be part of that agreement in the first place.